# Run a spider from an .exe file

Tags: python, scrapy, exe, py2exe

I don't know if there's already a question on the same subject. My english is not good enough to understand all the topics I saw on `stackoverflow.com` about web scraping and run a spider from an exe file.

So, I'm sorry if I ask a question which was already answered somewhere but : is it possible, after having written my spider, to launch it from an exe file instead of launching it from the `scrapy crawl xxx` ? Just by clicking on the .exe file, the computer will search the items I want on the website I crawl, and will give me a .csv file or .json file. I saw `py2exe` but it seems to be for the output of my spider. I don't understand it.

I hope I've been clear enough (it's not even clear in French in my head, and it's really hard to translate it in English).

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Hi, if it doesn't need to be .exe, you could just write a script that will do everything for you. You could call your python script from a Windows shell script, for example: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/win32/win32scripting.html

Comment: Yes, the problem is I want to give this program to people who know nothing about programming stuffs. I just want the easier way for them to use my spider. You think your solution is the easier?

Comment: I don't know what's easier *in your specific case*. But you can definitely write a simple bat file that the user can just click. You can put `python3.5 yourPythonScript.py` and it'll execute your spider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here : [How do I package a Scrapy script into a standalone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532596/how-do-i-package-a-scrapy-script-into-a-standalone-application)

Thanks to the help provided by [@juwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6908103/juwi)  !! I think it's the easier way for me...

Answer (score 2):

To run a python script, you need to have a python interpreter available on the machine.

So if you want to distribute your python script (your spider), you need to make sure that your users have a correct python environment set up.

### I

When you are dealing with technical people this is usually not a problem, just tell them they need to `install python 3.5` (or whatever you are using) and get the required modules with `pip`. They might even figure it out on their own.

### II

If you are dealing with non technical users, you don't want to make their live hard by requiring them to use the command-line or having to install all the dependencies.

Instead you can provide them with a **self-contained** package that includes: `your script`, the `python interpreter` and required `additional modules`.

There are several tools that can create these packages for you:

- PyInstaller - http://www.pyinstaller.org/ (this might be the easiest option)
- Py2exe - http://www.py2exe.org/
- some other...

See also these questions asked on stackoverflow:

- [How can I create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python)
- [How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You can just create your own module and specify the dependencies. Then, the users will be able to just `pip install` that one module and pip will install all the dependencies for them: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've already seen py2exe (which seems to be the solution to my problem) but I don't understand how it works. Could you explain it to me with simple words please?

It seems to work for a simple python script but I don't know how it works for a scrapy one...

Comment: Please try PyInstaller first, as it seams the easiest option. You can find the instructions on the website http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Ok, with pyinstaller, a directory dist was created and a .exe file also. But it doesn't crawl the website I want to crawl. Any other helpful idea?

Answer (score 0):

you must make CrawlerProcess`s cod under   `if __name__=='__main__':`  to  avoid run twice and error

Here is another possibility to run your spider as a standalone script or executable

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    
    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        # Your spider definition
    if __name__=='__main__':
        process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
          })
    
        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

You can find more information here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/practices.html